# Incomplete binary data between QSignal and QSlot

Tags: c++, qt, binary

I have in my Qt code a function f1() that emits a QSignal with a char array of binary data as parameter.
My problem is the QSlot that is connected to this QSignal receives this array but the data is incomplete: it receives the data until the first "0x00" byte. 
I tried to change the char [] to char*, didn't help.
How can I do to receive the full data, including the "0x00" bytes ?

```
connect(dataStream, &BaseConnection::GotPacket, this, &myClass::HandleNewPacket);

void f1()
{
  qDebug() << "Binary read = " << inStream.readRawData(logBuffer, static_cast<int>(frmIndex->dataSize));
//logBuffer contains the following hexa bytes: "10 10 01 30 00 00 30 00 00 00 01 00 D2 23 57 A5 38 A2 05 00 E8 03 00 00 6C E9 01 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A6 AF 01 00 00 00 00 00"
  Q_EMIT GotPacket(logBuffer, frmIndex->dataSize);

}

void myClass::HandleNewPacket(char p[LOG_BUFFER_SIZE], int size)
{
// p contains the following hexa bytes : "10 10 01 30"

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How did you determine that the data passed "stopped" at the first zero byte?

Comment: How is `frmIndex->dataSize` set?  Are you using `strlen` by any chance?  That aside, you'd be far better off using something like `QByteArray` rather than a simple array.

Comment: @Mat by debugging the code. I see the data as it is in the function vs the value of "p" in the QSlot.

Comment: @G.M. I get the length of the data I need to read from an external file. When reading the external file I set the frmIndex->dataSize.

Comment: @E.F: but are you sure what you're seeing in your debugger isn't simply using that `char*` as that type usually is, i.e. a null-terminated C string?

Comment: @Mat oh you were right... I stupid error.  I increased the pointer and the whole data is here, only the debugger doesn't show it.
I'm not used to work with hexa data so I didn't think about this option. Thanks !!